# How to count NUMBERS from google sheets when there is also a word there which doesn't need counting

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Can't find a function which allows me to count the numbers, add them up and then paste it onto the first row. As there are also words there, for description of what is being counted then I've not yet found a way to count numbers without the words becoming a source of error.

Already tried the use of different functions

Fix my table so i can start counting how many things i do in a day/year

[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2Mq6.png)

[Finished code in the sheet, big thanks to pnuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g53dg.png)

Comment: Hi Kevin, can you share a copy of your spreadsheet? That will surely help in getting help faster.

Comment: Added link to the sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(iferror(1*REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A4,"\d+"),0)))
```

and if you have cells in the selected range that are Number format and want those included in the addition, add those as well as a separate clause (ie append `+sum(A1:A4)`).